# Why prolog outputs a weird tree-like list?

Tags: prolog, primes, difference-lists

In this Prolog code I intend to list the first N primes,

```
(...)

biggerPrime(N,P) :-
    isPrime(N),
    P is N,
    !.

biggerPrime(N,P) :-
    N1 = N+1,
    biggerPrime(N1,P).

primeListAcc(0,A,R,R) :- !.

primeList(N,L) :-
    primeListAcc(N,1,[],L).

primeListAcc(N,A,L,R) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    biggerPrime(A,P),
    A1 is P+1,
    primeListAcc(N1,A1,[P|L],R).
```

And it works fine if I want the list ordered backwards:

```
?- primeList(5,L).
L = [11, 7, 5, 3, 2].
```

But if I change the last line of the code from [P|L] to [L|P] like this:

```
primeListAcc(N,A,L,R) :-
        N1 is N-1,
        biggerPrime(A,P),
        A1 is P+1,
        primeListAcc(N1,A1,[L|P],R).
```

I get:

```
?- primeList(5,L).
L = [[[[[[]|2]|3]|5]|7]|11].
```

What am I missing? This is driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, so you've discovered the problem of adding elements to the *end* of a list. In Prolog, we can do it with

```
add(X,L,Z):- L=[X|Z].
```

wait, what? How to read this? We must know the calling convention here. We *expect* `L` and `Z` to come in as *uninstantiated* variables, and we arrange for `L` from now on  to point to a newly created *cons* node with `X` at its head, and `Z` its tail. `Z` to be instantiated, possibly, in some future call.

IOW what we create here is an open-ended list, `L = [X|Z] = [X, ...]`:

```
primeList(N,L) :-
    primeListAcc(N,1,[],L).

primeListAcc(N,A,Z,L) :- N > 0,   % make it explicitly mutually-exclusive,
    N1 is N-1,                    %   do not rely on red cuts which are easily
    biggerPrime(A,P),             %   invalidated if clauses are re-arranged!
    A1 is P+1,                    
    L = [P|R],                    % make L be a new, open-ended node, holding P
    primeListAcc(N1,A1,Z,R).      % R, the tail of L, to be instantiated further

primeListAcc(0,A,R,R).            % keep the predicate's clauses together
```

We can see now that `Z` is not really needed here, as it carries the `[]` down the chain of recursive calls, unchanged. So we can re-write `primeListAcc` without the `Z` argument, so that its final clause will be

```
primeListAcc(0,A,R):- R=[].
```

Keeping `Z` around as uninstantiated variable allows for it to be later instantiated possibly with a non-empty list as well (of course, only *once* (unless backtracking occurs)). This forms the basis of "difference list" technique.

---

To answer your *literal* question - here, consider this interaction transcript:

```
1 ?- X=[a|b].

X = [a|b] 
2 ?- X=[a|b], Y=[X|c].

X = [a|b]
Y = [[a|b]|c]
```

the `[a|b]` output is just how a cons node gets printed, when its tail (here, `b`) is *not* a list. Atoms, as numbers, are *not* lists.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a list is either the empty list `[]` or a term with functor `'.'` and two arguments, whose second argument is a list. The syntax `[P|Ps]` is shorthand notation for the term `'.'(P, Ps)`, which is a list if `Ps` is a list (as is the case in your example). The term `'.'(Ps, P)`, on the other hand, which can also be written as `[Ps|P]` (as you are doing), is *not* a list if `P` is not a list. You can obtain a reverse list with `reverse/2`.