# Adding a tail in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail

I'm having trouble understanding how prolog works with lists. I'm trying to write a function that will add a tail to a given list and returns a new list. but my implementation does not work and I can't understand how to fix it. Here is what I have:

```
% add_tail(L,M,E) :- L is M with [E] appended.
% I wanna do this without using the append predicate

add_tail([E],[],E).
add_tail(List, [H|T], E):-
    add_tail(List1, T, E),
    List is [H|List1].
```

to clarify what i want this function to do, here is an example of an output:

```
?- add_tail(L,[1,2,3],4).
L = [1,2,3,4].
```

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733735/why-prolog-outputs-a-weird-tree-like-list/15743688#15743688). it is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_7.html) out:

```
append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).
append([],X,X).
```

The second line (`append([],X,X)`) simply states that appending an element `X` to an empty list is equal to that element itself (break condition). The first line states appending `Z` to a list `[X|Y]` (`X` is head, `Y` rest) results in a new list `[X|W]`, whereas `W` is the result of appending `Z` to `Y`.

**Example**

```
?- append([1,2,3],[4],L).
L = [1,2,3,4]
```

In your case you just need to reorder the parameters!

Comment: actually, you have an error in your definition. appending an element `X` to the end of an empty list `[]` should result in a list, not an element `X` itself.

Comment: @WillNess the example was not correct. This rule assumes that all arguments are lists. so if you my fact returns [X] instead of X, I would have something like [1,2,3,[4]].